# Assigning labels to unallocated space in HD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I want to format an unallocated space of 60GB in my hard disk to fat32(for installing Linux) using the fat32format GUI as described in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/52640/how-to-format-as-fat32-from-windows-7-vista/65466#65466?newreg=6831aa9514ed4ca494f690e1a8cefa08) page. But the problem is the windows disk manager doesn't allow me to assign label to this unallocated space.

This is the procedure I followed,

Right-click on unallocated space -> New Simple Volume -> Next -> Next -> Assign Letter -> Do not format this volume(also tried format as exFAT32/NTFS option) -> Next -> Finish

I get the following message,

[image]

Followed by this error message after hitting yes:

[image]

Looks like fat32format.exe cannot format a the unallocated space with assigning a label to the space. I found in some help forum that we have to tweak some beginning and end in regedit, but no explanation on how to do this. Please suggest a solution to this problem.

Comment: @whs There are 2 relevant options when I right click on the unallocated space in this tool - create and wipe partition. Hitting create shows an error. Should I wipe the partition before proceeding? If so, which option among Fill with zero, one, etc?

Comment: @whs Tried the wipe option. Doesn't help. It will be of great help if you can elaborate on the full procedure to go about this.

Comment: Someone deleted my comment. It was apparently something that the sheriffs did not like. So I will refrain from further comments. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this process of commands, this **does** involve formating:
`cmd` > `diskpart` (make sure you're using an Administrative CMD)

`select disk "X"` (Where X is the drive number seen in diskmanagement)

`select part Y` (Where Y is the partition number of the 60GB)

`format fs=fat32 quick` (**or**) `format fs=fat32 label=AnyLabelHere quick` if you want to give the partition a name.

`assign letter Z` (Where Z is the drive **letter** you want to assign)

`list volume` > To check/verify that the partitioning worked and is listed.

Comment: select part Y just skips the unallocated space and takes the next part. I ended up formatting my recovery partition to fat32 :( Is there any command to check the volume size of the part after 'select part Y'?

Comment: `Disk part` > `list volume` > `select volume X` > `list part`

Comment: It doesn't list unallocated space

Comment: When that doesn't work for me, I use Bootice. http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice.html